# Transactional Emails not sending in Magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail

I am having some issues where Magento 2 we are not getting any email confirmations of any sort. I have checked Magento configuration and everything is correct in terms of settings.

But when I have tail -f the mail log there is nothing being outputted to the log, its just blank.

I have also checked the exception log and there is nothing that appears in there to do with mail, not that I can see. I have also checked and the cron settings in the back-end are all correct.

Comment: Have you installed smtp extension for email ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up Cron Jobs for Magento

Check your Cron Jobs

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Your cron run could depend on your server. So I'll use Magento Official documentation

Login to your server using ssh and type

`which php`

Result will be something like this

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Add following cron jobs

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run

* * * * * /usr/bin/php <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run

* * * * * /usr/bin/php <magento install dir>/update/cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to turn on Postfix on the server, seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in try-cache block, so if any error occurs in code, it will show in your code.
First of all check that your email server is running with test php mail function.